# Followed The Google OmniAuth tutorial but getting rejected from Server, how to read the rejection notice

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

This is the tutorial I followed.  Scroll down to the Google open-id integration:

```
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview
```

On the server I get the following rejection message after clicking the login with google link:

```
WARNING: making https request to https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id without verifying server certificate; no CA path was specified.
processing by users omniauthcallbackscontroller failure as html
```

EDIT the following two lines fixed the CA path Warning but did nothing to fix the failure as html problem or move me forward

```
require "openid/fetchers"
OpenID.fetcher.ca_file = "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"
```

It then re-routes me to users/sign_in.

My devise config line looks like this:

```
config.omniauth :open_id, :store => OpenID::Store::Filesystem.new('/tmp'), :name => 'google', :identifier => 'https://www.google.com/acounts/o8/id', :require => 'omniauth-openid'
```

My research tells me that I'm probably hitting the openID servers but that I'm getting rejected.  Is there anyway to get more info from some sort of rejection notice?  What could be wrong with my request?

One thing I thought of was credentials for open ID but I didn't see anywhere in the tutorial where I was supposed to get or enter any credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the ca_path:

```
config.omniauth :open_id, :store => OpenID::Store::Filesystem.new('/tmp'), 
                :name => 'google', 
                :identifier => 'https://www.google.com/acounts/o8/id', 
                :require => 'omniauth-openid', 
                :client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_path => '/etc/ssl/certs'}}
```

And see if it works.

Comment: This seemed to have no effect on the result.  Do you have any idea on if google sends any message back explaining why they rejected the request?

Comment: Adding the follow 2 lines removed the CA Warning but did nothing to fix the failure as HTML problem. require "openid/fetchers"
  OpenID.fetcher.ca_file = "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"